# Can I process command output just before sending it to a file (one liner)?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have a command processing function that runs its arguments and outputs the results to a file. The outputs of those commands must now be PROCESSED just before going to the file.

**I have only one requirement: `echo "var is: $var"` must show the outcome which will be used further down in the code.**

THIS BREAKS MY REQUIREMENT: `"${@:1}" | perl -pe 's/\**//g' >> './test.log'`

I imagine something like this:

```
"${@:1}" 1>> perl -pe 's/\**//g' >> './test.log'
```

but it does not work.

I have simplified my code down to the following:

```
process() {
    "${@:1}" 1>>'./test.log'
}

process eval 'var=$(echo -e "*****ONE *****WORD"); echo -e "$var";'
echo "var is: $var"
```

Currently this function outputs:

```
 screen :"var is: *****ONE *****WORD"

 logfile:"*****ONE *****WORD"
```

.

Required result:

```
 screen :"var is: *****ONE *****WORD" 

 logfile:"ONE WORD"
```

How can I achieve this?

**PS. muru asked me why I use eval. I answered, because there is no other way to populate the variable without duplicating code. Unfortunately our discussion under his answer was deleted.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `eval` here to set the variable for some weird reason, it must be run in the current shell, which is not the case with pipes. So you probably need process substitution:

```
process () {
    "${@}" > >(perl ... >> test.log)
}
```

For example:

```
$ process () {
 "${@}" > >(perl -pe 's/\**//g' >> test.log)
}
$ process eval 'var=$(echo -e "*****ONE *****WORD"); echo -e "$var";'
$ echo "var is: $var"
var is: *****ONE *****WORD
$ cat test.log
ONE WORD
```