# Script hanging when using tee and wait, why?

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, tee, wait

I'm running a script which automates snapraid for my NAS server. It's a script I found online and it was working without issue on Debian 9. I updated to Debian 10 last week and the script now hangs in places it wasn't on Debian 9. I think I've narrowed the issue down to the tee and wait commands.

I've shortened the script to the below snippet for testing and the issue is happening, this is why I think it's tee and wait.

```
#!/bin/bash

# location of the snapraid binary
SNAPRAID_BIN="/usr/local/bin/snapraid"

# redirect all output to screen and file
> $TMP_OUTPUT
exec 3>&1 4>&2
# NOTE: Not preferred format but valid: exec &> >(tee -ia "${TMP_OUTPUT}" )
exec > >(tee -a "${TMP_OUTPUT}") 2>&1

# run the snapraid DIFF command
echo "###SnapRAID DIFF [`date`]"
$SNAPRAID_BIN diff
# wait for the above cmd to finish
wait
echo
echo "DIFF finished [`date`]"
```

I ran htop also to see what was happening and the processes created from the snapraid commands just don't end.

wait is doing exactly what it should, wait, but why did this work before and not now?

Full script is here: https://pastebin.com/gJqnz875

Comment: the difference between debian 9 and 10 is that in debian 9 the `wait` wasn't actually waiting for the `tee` to finish piping all the output; ie even then it wasn't working as its author imagined it. In the bash from debian 10 the `wait` works as "expected" and waits ... forever ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tee` inside the process substitution will not exit until it gets an eof on its stdin or some error happens.

And, since its stdin is a pipe, it will only get an `EOF` on its stdin when all the handles to its writing end are closed.

So, you'll have to save the original stdout and stderr, and then, before the `wait`, redirect them to the originals; dup'ing fds via the `new>&old` cause the `old` fd to be closed.

```
exec {out}>&1 {err}>&2
exec > >(tee -a output) 2>&1
...
exec >&$out 2>&$err
wait $(pgrep -P "$$")
```

Also, only in newer versions of bash `wait` also waits for processes running in a `> >(...)` process substitution; that's why I used `wait $(pgrep -P "$$")` instead of simply `wait` (`pgrep -P` finds processes by their parent). Also see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/524570/308316) for this and other pitfalls related to `> >(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It definitely makes sense now. It was driving me crazy. I should be able to get it running now :)